# Draw line on mouse move and detect line collision in Unity2D and Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I used the code for line collison from http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/draw-line-mouse-move-detect-line-collision-unity2d-unity3d/ and it's working all right. It detects when line collides with itself, but I need to check collision with other objects (lets say a platform). I added this function in script:

```
private bool isLineCollidedWithOtherObject()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(pointsList[pointsList.Count-1]));
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit))
    {
          if(hit.collider)
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and also added while checking for collision

```
if(isLineCollide() && isLineCollidedWithOtherObject());
```

But it's not working. I added `Box2dcollider` to platform (Player). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this thread, specifically the linked post from the devs about raycasting from the camera in 3d space in a 2d sprite game:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-2d-raycast-from-mouse-to-screen.211708/#post-1424457

the docs for the functions mentioned are here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.GetRayIntersection.html